# How can I use JmDNS successfully on Android?

Tags: java, android, jmdns

According to the topic...
I am a newcomer of Android!!!!
I have been tried to implement JmDNS successfully on Android for 2 more weeks...
(Not only on Google IDEOS phone,but also on Eclipse)...
I,ve been tried the "TestBonjour" code (comment 22)...
 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2917
But it's still not working!!
Could anyone can help me to solve this question?
Thanks a million and forgive my poor English!!

Comment: Java multi-cast DNS-->JmDNS for Bonjour service detection of Android.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your phone it works.  See our open source example here:

http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-plus/source/browse/trunk/src/org/tunesremote/LibraryActivity.java

Also on some HTC phones there is a known WIFI driver bug preventing mDNS packets from being received.  You can read about that here:

http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-plus/issues/detail?id=1